Calling dbt macro from model in snowflake
I have a macro in dbt to convert array to dict
{% macro array_to_dict(ARR, KEY_FIELD_NAME, VALUE_FIELD_NAME, execute=True)  -%}
    {% set v_sql  %}
        SELECT OBJECT_AGG(
            PARSE_JSON(f.{{VALUE_FIELD_NAME}}):{{KEY_FIELD_NAME}},
            PARSE_JSON(f.{{VALUE_FIELD_NAME}}):{{VALUE_FIELD_NAME}}
        ) AS json_object
        FROM LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON('{{ARR}}')) AS f
        GROUP BY f.this
    {% endset %}
    {{ log("SQL to run :" ~ v_sql, info=True) }}
    {% set result = run_query(v_sql) %}

    {% if execute %}
        {{ log("results " ~ result, info=True ) }}
        {% set v_tr_id = result %}
    {% else %}
        {% set v_tr_id = NULL %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ return(v_tr_id) }}
{%- endmacro %}


I want to call this macro on a table column
select
    id,
    {{ array_to_dict('p', 'key', 'value') }}
from {{ source('abc', 'test') }}


this gives me error
000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 5 at position 38
invalid identifier 'p'
how could I make this work?

what is the error?
